# Swift: failed to import bridging header potentially due to multiple chained imports

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, bridging-header

I know at first glance, you will say this is a duplicate question that has been asked by lots of people. However, after doing some research, I think my situation is different from previous ones.

I am having this "failed to import bridging header" error when I tried to import objective-C files(that also import other files) into swift through bridging header. For example:

**Person** is a class written in objective-c, in the header and implementation files of this class, it also imports other **local** objC classes like "Animal", and also some **pod frameworks** such as "firebase".

When I tried to import this kind of class in bridging header, xcode reports the error of "failed to import bridging header". But when I import a simple objective-C class that does not import other files, everything is fine.

My guess is my objectiveC files rely on some third party frameworks and also some internal classes. When I import these kinds of files, I do not import all the necessary classes this targeted file uses?

So what might be the solution for this issue? The project I am working on is an objC based one, so most of the project are done in objC. Is it possible to import everything into the bridging header at once so that I can grab anything I want in the swift file?

Thank you so much! Having been stuck in this for half a day :(